# Unable to add a new Force Project on Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, ide, force

I am trying to take Metadata backup from a sandbox before refreshing it, I used to take this metadata backup using Eclipse Force IDE on other computer and now I have a new one and I have installed Eclipse 2019-06 version and installed the Force IDE plugin but I am unable to create a project. When I click on the New Force Project it's not creating any project. I have changed the Force IDE version but it's not allowing me to install any other versions. Can someone help me?

Thank you

Comment: Salesforce is ending support for Eclipse IDE next month.  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.eclipse.meta/eclipse/debugger_update_ide.htm  Your alternatives are to use the free Microsoft VS Code IDE with Salesforce extensions or a paid IDE tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not really use [Eclipse](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.eclipse.meta/eclipse/ide_install.htm) as its support will be completely ended by October 12, 2019 - in about 1 month.

> Force.com IDE is in a maintenance-only state. We still provide support
>   for the product through our official channels, but updates prior to
>   October 12, 2019 will be only for critical security issues that arise.
>   On October 12, 2019, we will no longer provide support or updates of
>   any kind for Force.com IDE. On that date, we will also begin archiving
>   documentation and removing download links for the product. We
>   recommend that you start migrating to Salesforce Extensions for [Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=salesforce.salesforcedx-vscode) or one of the great tools made by our partners. For more
>   information, see [The Future of Salesforce IDEs](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/12/the-future-of-salesforce-ides.html) on the Salesforce
>   Developers Blog.

Comment: Thank you for the information, i was able to install the Visual code and its working.